# Pelican - add image to summary

Tags: pelican

I'm using pelican to create a website. I'm trying to add an image to the summary so that the summary always starts with an image.

I tried adding the image to the summary in the metadata (using markdown) but it only shows up on the index page and not on the other pages (in the example below the image does not show in the Posts page). I also have to add the image in the same line as the text which sometimes renders in a weird way (some text is to the side of the image depending on the image size).

Here is an example of the metadata:

```
Title: this is my title
Slug: slug
Date: 2017-05-04 23:00
Category: Posts
Tags: pelican
Author: Eyal
Summary: ![figure 1](images/fig1.png) and this is my post summary
```

I also tried to use the summary plugin but that but that did not work at all.

What is the easiest way to add an image to the summary? I was hoping to avoid modifying the html code if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the image as a field metadata in your article, say it "`Cover`", like this:

```
Title: this is my title
Slug: slug
Date: 2017-05-04 23:00
Category: Posts
Tags: pelican
Author: Eyal
Cover: images/fig1.png
Summary: and this is my post summary
```

So you can use it in your template in this way.

```
{% if article.cover %}<img src="{{ article.cover }}" alt="">{% endif %} {{ article.summary }}
```

This line looks for `Cover` key in the metadata, and if there is one, create the `img` tag. If is not, then simply pass.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate on the line in the template. I'm new to pelican and find it confusing. I'm using the pelican-ipynb plugin to convert a jupyter notebook to the desired content. I have a ipynb and ipynb-meta files. I can edit the metadata in the ipynb-meta but I'm not sure what to do with the last line you posted to use in my template.

Comment: My mistake! It needs an `img` tag.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still missing something very basic. What do you mean by template? Where do I add this line?

Comment: I added the line you recommended to the article.html template and the results was an added cover image at the beginning of each article and not on the index page and the posts page as I was hoping.

Comment: Hi @EyalS., it's correct... there's a template for each case, just look the documentation to find what templete need to suit your needs: http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/themes.html#structure

Comment: I think I'm really close. Sorry if my questions seem very basic - I do not have any experience with html or pelican. I'm using bootstrap3. I changed the article_list.html template and the index page looks great! My problem is that the images cannot be found on the category page. I looked at the category.html and it uses {% extends "article_list.html" %}. The problem is that the output html is in a different folder so it cannot find the images. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: Okay. It was a simple fix. I wrote /images/fig1.png and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Ad it there where `article.summary` already is used. I use pelican-theme **alchemy**  (that uses bootstrap) and  `article.summary` is in `index.html`. I extended it as follows:

```
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <h4 class="title"><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h4>
    <div class="content">
      {{ article.summary|striptags }}
      {% if article.cover %}           
         <div class="container"><div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left: 0px;  padding-right: 0px;">
           <img src="{{ article.cover }}" class="img-fluid">
           </div></div>   
      {% endif %} 
    </div>
  </div>
```

This works for me with the pictures in the *images*-folder.
[image]

**But** I have an other problem: the posts do not find the pictures in the same *images*-folder :-(

Answer (score 0):

For those using the AboutWilson template in Pelican I have managed to make it work as well by adding the following code in the  `index.html` file (in the template folder)

```
{% if article.cover %}
Cover:
<span> 
    <img src="{{ article.cover }}" alt=""> 
</span>
{% endif %}
```

[image]